# Spring Security get logged in value

Tags: java, spring-security

I have a JSP page that is getting user information from my accout object in Java in a way that I was doing log in's before I implemented spring security.  I want my button to show what I have in my div when the user is logged in.  I was using the session before but now that I am using Spring Security it thinks that its not logged in.  I searched google and Stack to try and find an answer to my question but I keep coming up with blanks.  Here is what I have in my JSP.

```
<div id="topRightMenu" class="f-right">
                <% if(    session.getAttribute("auth") == null
                        || session.getAttribute("auth").toString() == "false"
                        || session.getAttribute("Account") == null) { %>


                    <div id="login-form">
                        <form action="/<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method="post" id="loginForm">
                            Username: <input class="text small" type="text" name="j_username" value="" /><br/>
                            Password: <input class="text small" type="password" name="j_password" value="" /><br/>
                            <label class="uiButton uiButtonLarge btnLogin">
                                <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" value="login" />
                            </label>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <button class="f-right" id="loginButton">Sign In</button>

                <% } else { %>
                    <ul class="noMarkers grid">
                        <li><a href="/account/edit/" title="Click to View Account Information">Account</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/profile/<%= Acc.getAccountID() %>" title="Click to View Your Profile">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/help" title="Click to Get Help">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/account/logout" title="Log Out">Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <% } %>
```

The sign in button is supposed to change to the links but its not.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [taglib provided by Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/taglibs.html). In particular, you could use the `<sec:authorize>` tag:

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    ....
</sec:authorize>
```

From its documentation:

> A tag which outputs the body of the tag if the configured access expression evaluates to true for the currently authenticated principal.

For an overview of the functions you can use in the `access` expression above, check [this section](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/el-access.html) of the reference docs.

Comment: I am still a little confused on how to actually do this.  I added the tag lib to the page now but am still unclear on how to get this to work properly.

Comment: Try wrapping both branches of your original `<% if %>` in a separate `<sec:authorize>` tag: the first with `access="isAnonymous()"` the second with `access="isAuthenticated()"`. If something still doesn't work, update your question with the new version of the JSP and the exact description of the problem, otherwise it won't be easy to help you.